# How can I make an XML file produce the correct output/data?

Tags: python, xml

I'm using the following code which prints the correct results to the console, but when I look at the file content it's incorrect:

```
def xmls (id):
    myfile = open("items2.xml", "wb")
    xml_node = etree.Element("node")
    item = etree.SubElement(xml_node, 'Item')
    etree.SubElement(item, 'ID').text = id

    # create a new XML file with the results
    mydata = ET.tostring(xml_node)
    print(mydata)

    myfile.write(mydata)
    myfile.close()
```

Console output:

```
b"<node><Item><ID>1</ID></Item></node>"
b"<node><Item><ID>2</ID></Item></node>"
```

But the file has only one ID:

```
<node><Item><ID>2</ID></Item></node>
```

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) your file for *appending* (`"a"`), not *writing* (`"w"`):

```
myfile = open("items2.xml", "ab")
```

With `"w"` anything that's already in the file gets overwritten:

> open for writing, truncating the file first

With `"a"` you get:

> open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists